# 'Is home page' condition with different store views in magento not working

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to show banner only on home page. I am using `$this->getIsHomePage()` in `header.phtml` from my theme. 
I have also created store views for multiple languages. 
But when i change store view on home page `$this->getIsHomePage()` condition returns `false`.
I think its due to change in `url` like this.
`/magento/?___store=french&___from_store=default`
How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`getIsHomePage` has a bug in it. It does not return true if you have get parameters in it.
For example if you cal it in `example.com/?a=1` it will return false.
Instead of `getIsHomepage` use this:

```
$action = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->getFullActionName();
if ($action == 'cms_index_index') {
    //your are on the homepage
}
else {
    //not on homepage
}
```

You can use this method anywhere, without having to access the header block.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php 
    $is_homepage = Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_header')->getIsHomePage();
    if($is_homepage):
        echo 'homepage';
    else:
        echo 'not homepage';
    endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If anybody wants to stick to `getIsHomePage` function, it can still be used following below steps:

Firstly make a copy of `app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Header.php` to same path from `Mage` dir in `local` like `app/code/local/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Header.php`.

Open the file you just copied in `local` codepool.

Then go to line that says `public function getIsHomePage()` or around line no. 51(if the file hasn't already been overriden yet) and replace "getIsHomePage" function with below code:

```
public function getIsHomePage()
{
    $homeUrl = $this->getUrl('')
    $currentUrl = $this->getUrl('*/*/*', array('_current'=>true, '_use_rewrite'=>true));
    if (strpos($currentUrl, '?') !== false) $currentUrl = array_shift(explode('?', $currentUrl));
    return $homeUrl == $currentUrl;
}
```

So now the `getIsHomePage` function will ignore parameters starting with `?` in url, thus it will work across multiple store views.

Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

```
$is_homepage = Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_header')->getIsHomePage();
if($is_homepage)
{
    echo "You are on Homepage!";
} else {
    echo "You are NOT on Homepage!";
}
```

Please try this :)

Comment: I tried it :) Doesn't seem to work with parameters, see accepted answer.