# $this->getIsHomePage() - Fix for Store Views

Tags: php, phtml, header, home

I am trying to use this code, [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113366/how-to-make-logo-only-h1-on-homepage-in-magento), in the header.phtml file on my [Magento 1.9.x website](https://www.tugasunwear.com). For some reason, even on the home page at .com/ or .com/?SID= it is still applying H3 where it should be H1.

Does anyone know why this might be happening? Do I need other info on the page?

```
<?php if ($this->getIsHomePage()):?>
  <h1 class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt(); ?></strong></h1>
  <?php else: ?>
  <h3 class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt(); ?></strong></h3>
  <?php endif ?>
```

This code is also running to test against false positives - This code works but is only doing an echo on the code, not actually rendering it to provide the alt text:

```
<div id="are-we-home" style="display: none; ">
  <?php if($routeName == 'cms' && $identifier == 'home') { echo 'You are in Homepage!'; } else { echo 'You are NOT in Homepage!'; } ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug. I think you're getting bitten by the same issue this guy is: ['Is home page' condition with different store views in magento not working](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/43533/is-home-page-condition-with-different-store-views-in-magento-not-working)

Replace your homepage check with this:

```
<?php 
  $action = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->getFullActionName();
  if ($action == 'cms_index_index'):
?>

  <h1 class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt(); ?></strong></h1>

<?php else: ?>

  <h3 class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt(); ?></strong></h3>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: This looks great for basic text, but how do I have PHP render inside of it? `<h1 class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt(); ?></strong></h1>`

Comment: I edited my answer to include your code - It's an H1 on the home page, and h3 on every other page

Comment: Thanks! I think there's a ? missing on the closing php endif - got an error when trying to wrap in a DIV.

I'm also getting the error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '='` when trying to load this code. It's referring to this line `<h1 class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt(); ?></strong></h1>`

Comment: ack - typo: missed the $ on $action in the first statement. and the last line should have a ? at the beginning and end: <?php endif; ?>. updated.

Comment: Looks like those edits fix it all. I'm seeing the logo alt text change between h1 and h3 like desired. Thanks so much!