# Unable to get CMS page identifier

Tags: magento-1.9, cms, phtml

I am trying to get CMS page identifier with `Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier();` in a footer.phtml but for some reason I am getting `no-route` on all the pages.

It used to work before but not anymore. My Magento version is 1.9.3.8. Am I missing something here?

I want to get the home page Identifier so I can use if/else statements to show a different message in homepage footer.

Update: I have tried both the solutions provided by @pawan below, apparently they did not work.

Comment: do you want to show message on only home page. Right ?

Comment: there are two messages. One will be on the home page and other one rest of the pages.

Comment: Please see my Answer, if have any issue let me know.

Comment: did you try my solution ?

Comment: See my Edit in answer.

Comment: @pawan it did not work :(

Comment: All 3 codes are working on my local.

Comment: @KevinS, did you get any solutions ?

Comment: @ShashankKumrawat not yet

Comment: @KevinS can you confirm that you have no modules and that all settings are from a clean vanilla Magento 1.9.3.8 install?

Comment: @KevinS something tells me that you have a malformed XML tag in your theme that's applying `cms_index_noRoute` to all pages

Comment: Is your footer maybe cached?

Comment: @Haim I tried on different site on the different server and still same issue. Pawel, I always clear cache after making changes.

Comment: @kevin can you confirm that this is happening on a clean vanilla site with no theme or extensions?

Comment: Please check it in all cms page url key set or not.

Comment: please upload your footer.phtml and cms page screenshot from admin

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code:

```
$routeName = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRouteName(); 
$identifier = Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier();

if($routeName == 'cms' && $identifier == 'home') {
    echo 'Message for Home page';
} else {
    echo 'Common message for others';
}
```

If above code not work, You can alternatively use:

```
if(Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_header')->getIsHomePage()) {
    echo 'Message for Home page';
} else {
    echo 'Common message for others';
}
```

Answer [Source](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-how-to-check-if-current-page-is-homepage/)

**Update I**

Another way to check Home Page by [Marius](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/43533/is-home-page-condition-with-different-store-views-in-magento-not-working)

```
$action = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->getFullActionName();
    if ($action == 'cms_index_index') {
        echo 'Message for Home page';
    }
else {
     echo 'Common message for others';
}
```

**Update II**

It can be done using CSS

```
<div style="display: none;" class="home-msg">Message for Home page</div>
<div class="rest-msg">Common message for others</div>

<style type="text/css">
    .cms-index-index .rest-msg{display: none;}
    .cms-index-index .home-msg{display: block;}
</style>
```

Comment: Both of the solutions did not work.

Comment: could you check home page identifier in admin ?

Comment: the url key is home

Comment: after `$action = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->getFullActionName();` when I do `echo` of `$action` it returns `cms_index_noRoute`

Comment: if you are not able to check home page, it can be done using CSS

Comment: for SEO purposes I cannot use CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps and try.

1. Disable Cache and see if that is working as expected.
2. If it is working then that should be related to cache.
3. I suggest keeping different footer template for the homepage. You can achieve this by changing the footer template in homepage using "Layout Update XML".

Hope this helps. Please try.

Comment: did it help Kevin?